# Object doesn't support this property or method runtime error in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am encountering an

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Runtime error in excel vba.

**Note** : The code works fine in my laptop.This error happened when I migrated the code to my desktop pc.

Below is the **UPDATED** code.

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument

Dim ro1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False

ie.navigate "url"

Set htmldoc = ie.document

Set ro1 = htmldoc.getElementById("table id").getElementsByTagName("tr")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(k, j) = rows(k).Children(0).textContent
```

`ro1(k).Children(0).textContent`  is the error part.

I have checked Tools->References. Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library has been checked.

Can anyone please guide me for this ?

Comment: Start by adding a line `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and then `Debug`->`Compile` to identify variables and objects that aren't properly declared or are being misused,  Keep compiling until no more warnings.

Comment: What is `rows(k).Children(0)`? Run in Immediate Window: `?TypeName(rows(k).Children(0))`

Comment: rows is a collection of <tr> tags.Each <tr> has <td> tags as children.So rows(k).Children(0).textContent fetches 0th <td> tag from each row.

Comment: @ashleedawg I tried what you said and it compiles perfectly.Mine is an runtime error.

Comment: What about rows(k).Children(0).InnerText?

Comment: Try using a different word besides `rows` .  Also, I suspect that if you copied the _exact_ same code _back_ to your laptop, it wouldn't work there either. (If it did, that could be a symptom of the issue,)

Comment: @sktneer I want one <td> tag at a time.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the changes you made as well as more information and sample data.  More info: [mcve] and also [ask]

Comment: PLease find the updated code above.

Comment: I suspect there are simply different Internet Explorer versions on your Laptop and PC and the one on your PC does not support `textContent`. Have you tried `innerText` at all?

Comment: @user3126632 I only replaced `rows(k).Children(0).textContent` with `rows(k).Children(0).InnerText`. Did you try that?

Comment: Actually there is one other code that is working with textContent.So I guess there should not be any problem there.

Comment: @sktneer That's the answer.Replaced textContent with InnerText .Please post as answer with needed explanatiion

Comment: @user3126632 Glad it resolved your issue. I have posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using InnerText instead of `textContent` and see if that works for you.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(k, j) = rows(k).Children(0).InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding a line `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and then `Debug`->`Compile` to identify variables and objects that aren't properly declared or are being misused,  Keep compiling until no more warnings.

Also, don't use the word **`ROWS`** as an object name.  `Rows` already means something in Excel & VBA.

[Here is a list of reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) that should be avoided.  (I realize it's labelled Access 2007 but the list is very similar, and it's surprisingly difficult to find an recent 'official' list for Excel VBA.)

Comment: I replaced rows with ro1.But that is still not serving the purpose.
Note : Code runs fine on my laptop.

Comment: you replaced **all** occurrences iin the project?  Aldo did you add `Option Explicit` to all modules in the project?

Comment: ok so did you declare `htmldoc` ?  Or is that declared elsewhere in code that wasn't shared?

Comment: Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.IHTMLDocument   is declared in the code.

Comment: okay, not in the code you shared.  Also I don't see a target URL being assigned to an object.  What page is this trying to open?  Also what is the value of `k` and `j`?  This would be much easier with all of the related information.